# How to write a auto executable script in php?

Tags: php, executable, cron

**From the basic of php i know that php needs to have some action/request to execute** so i am little confused about how to do it. I know it can be done but don't know how.

I want to write a php script which will run in server every 6 hours and update the database info from an api.

**More Info:**

The server i am currently working is in linux. But i want to know how i can do it in both linux and windows.

**UPDATE:**

Cron does not find my script. I don't know where is the problem is. I have used this command in my cpanel

`0 */6 * * * php public_html/path_to_dir/file_to_run.php`

I have setup the cron so cPanel send me email. The email i am getting is showing some error.

`/bin/sh: 0: command not found`

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Have you considered using chron jobs for this?

Comment: @Pradeep: cron. Has nothing to do with the Greek chronos :-)

Comment: @Quentin @Fabio M. @Bobby Jack: Update the problem. Please check!

Comment: Did you install `php5-cli` package? Does the file `/usr/bin/php` exists?

Answer (score 6):

You need to have something run the script on a timer. This is typically going to be cron (on UNIX based systems such as Linux, OS X, BSD, etc) or Windows Task Schedular (on Windows).

Comment: This said, the timer doesn't need to run on the server, though. If the PHP script is accessible via the Interwebs, any machine with a cronjob defined can call it, for eaxample via cUrl or wget.

Comment: So, i will need two types of scripts for windows and linux? 
@Boldewyn: Not sure what you mean :( Can you give any links where i can start?

Comment: No. One script. You just need to use a different program to run it on a timer. (Although I think you can get cron for Windows)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule a process in Unix.

Comment: this is the best way to do it - the only thing is you need to make sure your host supports it AND you need to know how to connect to your server using SSH (google the program called Putty)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you're using a Linux based S.O.

1. Install the **php5-cli** package as
   root with `apt-get install php5-cli`
   (or your pkg manager).
2. Write and test your script
   with the PHP CLI, `php
   filename.php`.
3. Login as selected
   user and set up a crontab using
   `crontab -e`
4. Write the crontab line:    `* */6 * * * php /full-path/filename.php`

`/var/log/messages` should log the crontab activities.

Comment: Hi, i am using this bit of code for adding the corn job `0 */6 * * * php /full-path/filename.php` will it run every 6 hours?

Comment: Update the problem. Please check!